# Saving related data from different components to Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on a ReactJS application which uses a Redux store to manage the application state.

The application has a feature that allows user to submit filters from various dropdown/select elements on the page. *These dropdown/select filter elements are wired to the Redux store*, so when various events take place, for example user selects a value then this data is saved to the redux store.

I am working on developing a filter group functionality whereby users can create 'filter groups' on the page and then create **multiple** instances of filters within the group and select value(s) from them. At the moment the Redux store only saves once instance of each filter value.

Whenever a user creates a filter group on the page, I want to save a filter group ID AND the selected values of the filters within it to the Redux store.

My initial thoughts are to set a filter group ID prop on each dropdown filter component and so when one of actions in the filter component get fired, the filter group id will be handy to save it to the store. One of the concerns I have is - what happens to the data in the Redux store if the user deletes an instance of the filter from the page? Does whatever data that was saved by that instance get deleted from the store too? If not, how do I handle this?

In addition to the concerns I outlined above, it would be helpful to get advice/suggestions on alternative ways to achieve the 'filter group' functionality.

Much appreciated!